# prolog programming there is someone?

Tags: prolog

maintaining a variable
sorry for my English

this is my code

```
stampa_diagnosi(X) :- gia_chiesto(S, 'si'), sintomo(S, M), not(sintomo(S, X)), M \= X,
nl, write('Una possibile diagnosi è: '), write(X), nl,

write('il paziente ha un peso minore di 65 KG? (1, 2, 3) '),nl,read(P),peso(P), nl.

peso(1) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura1(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
peso(2) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura2(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
peso(3) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura3(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.

cura1(centaurea_minore) :- write('La cura è di 10 gocce .').

cura2(centaurea_minore) :- write('La cura è di 30 gocce .').

cura3(centaurea_minore) :- write('La cura è di 40 gocce .').

cura1(agnocasto) :- write('La cura è di 10 gocce .').

cura2(agnocasto) :- write('La cura è di 30 gocce .').

cura3(agnocasto) :- write('La cura è di 40 gocce .').
```

how do I maintain the value of X of diagnosis that is lost when I ask the question of the weight of the patient?

My question requires me once I found the cure based on the weight I have to select the right one as I do??

Obviously I have a lot of care and care for each three solutions

Comment: maybe write your question with more details in italian and use translate.google.com  , it's hard to see what you're asking or what the problem is

Comment: if this is homework tag as such

Answer (score 0):

> how do I maintain the value of X of diagnosis that is lost when I ask the question of the weight of the patient?

Very simple. Follow the DRY principle, use an output argument and rewrite

```
peso(1) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura1(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
peso(2) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura2(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
peso(3) :- write('Possibile cura: '), cura3(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
```

to

```
peso(N, X) :-
    write('Possibile cura: '), cura1(X), nl, write(' ----- '), nl,spiegacome.
```

(and update `stampa_diagnosi` accordingly.)